# Delete all file and keep the latest using powershell

Tags: powershell, file, backup

I have a file that i backup daily, as sample like this :

Before deleting all but the latest :

```
Folder C:\Backup\
File : 
Backup1-Database-A.bak | 1/10/2020 1:24 PM
Backup2-Database-A.bak | 2/10/2020 1:24 PM
Backup1-Database-B.bak | 1/10/2020 1:24 PM
Backup2-Database-B.bak | 2/10/2020 1:24 PM
Backup2-Database-B.bak | 3/10/2020 1:24 PM
```

Desired state after deleting all but the latest :

```
Folder C:\Backup\
File : 
Backup2-Database-A.bak | 2/10/2020 1:24 PM
Backup2-Database-B.bak | 3/10/2020 1:24 PM
```

How can I keep the latest file for each database?

I'm using this script, but it deletes all `.bak` so the backup of database A is gone, but I want to keep the latest for each database.

```
$mydays = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)
$path = "C:\Backup\"
Get-Childitem -path $path -recurse -force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.name -like "*.bak" -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $mydays} | Remove-Item -Force
```

Comment: If you just want that last (one) days worth then try `$mydays = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)`.

Comment: @jfrmilner yes, i tried -1 . but it delete all, and not keep the latest file, maybe i wrong at name -like script

Comment: instead of testing for a certain date ... just sort by date and keep only the newest one. [*grin*]

Comment: As aside, it is more efficient to use `-Filter '*.bak'` than `$_.name -like "*.bak"`. and if your PowerShell version is 3.0 or newer, use switch `-File` instead of `!$_.PSIsContainer`

Comment: @Lee_Dailey yes, thankyou. but how i can skip the all LastWriteTime, because it will delete all and i want to keep the 2 file A & B in the LastWriteTime

Comment: @lass - it looks like mklement0 has covered that in his Answer with the `Group-Object` command. [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Lee_Daily](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) suggests, rather than using a time window to filter by, it is simpler to sort your files by last write time and delete all but the latest files.

The challenge is to determine which files relate to the same database and should therefore be considered as a *group*, so that you keep the most recent backup *in each group*.

The code below uses the following approach:

- The [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) cmdlet allows you to group the input files by the shared part of the file names that indicates the database.

  - Passing script block `{ $_.Name -replace '^Backup\d+-' }` to `Group-Object`
    uses the regex-based [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) to make it group the input file objects by the shared name part that indicates the source database, by removing the `'Backup<n>-'` prefix.
  - E.g., the result for both `'Backup1-Database-A.bak'` and `'Backup2-Database-A.bak'` is just `'Database-A.bak'`, so the two files are grouped together.
- The files in each resulting group can then be sorted by last write time in descending order, with
  [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object).
- You can exclude the first - and therefore most recent - file from the output with [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) `-Skip 1`.
- The resulting files - all but the most recent ones for each database - can then be sent to [`Remove-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item).

```
$path = 'C:\Backup'
Get-Childitem -Path $path -Recurse -Force -File -Filter *.bak | 
  Group-Object { $_.Name -replace '^Backup\d+-' } | 
    ForEach-Object { 
      $_.Group | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 1 |
        Remove-Item -Force -Whatif  
    }
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Also note the simplification of the initial file selection: `-File` (PSv3+) limits output to files only (not also directories), and `-Filter *.bak` is an efficient way to filter by filename extension.